# ADF not accepting third party cookies

Tags: experience-manager, dd4t, sites-9, ambient-data-framework

Inside of our DD4T implementation (using Tridion 9) we are trying to add third party script for cookies. However, once it is added after accepting cookies all pages are crashing with error:
[image]

[image]

We noticed that one cookie that is saving information when cookies are accepted is in the format DateTime object. Once this cookie is deleted or all cookies are cleared, the site will start working.
We tested this also with a simple scenario. Setup one test cookie that is in DateTime object format and we also reproduced the above problem.
ADF is only used as a module included in web.config in order to enable the proper work of XPM. On staging ADF is present and on live not, so we tested there above scenario and we could not reproduce the problem. Accepting cookies will not crash that environment.

Wondering if there is some easy solution for this in order to force ADF to accept DateTime object cookies or is this some bug?
Is anyone had similar issue?

Comment: Hi Bojana, I think you may need to update your Sdl.Web.Delivery via Nuget (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sdl.Web.Delivery/) to work with Sites 9 microservices.

Comment: This looks like a bug in ADF deserialization code. Please contact SDL Support to obtain a fix.

Comment: Maybe this is a separate one but as @RickPannekoek mentioned there were a bug and SDL provided hotfix (before providing hotfix we tested dlls with them that are included in hotfix). However, now I have one additional problem. The hotfix is following CD_11.0.0.21335 but our application is based on NuGet and necessary libraries (dlls) are coming through SDL.Web.Delivery nuget.However, we are using the 11.0.1062 version of SDL.Web.Delivery and all higher versions till 1095 are not working (issue still occurring).How to know if a hotfix is available in NuGet and which NuGet version I need to use?